# how to print_r a query in codeigniter? and where i mean controller or model

Tags: codeigniter

```
public function show_project() {
    $this->load->model('OPM_model/get_data');
    $data['project_data'] = $this->get_data->get_all_projects();
    foreach ($data['project_data'] as $p_id) {
        $user_id = $p_id->project_assigned_user_ids;
        $id = explode(",", $user_id);
        foreach ($id as $value) {
            $ide = $this->get_data->get_developer_name_by_id($value);
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($ide);
        }
    }

    //  $ide= $this->get_data->get_developer_name_by_id($id);

    die();
}
```

Comment: you can print it in model using $this->db->last_query();

Comment: what you exactly want??

Comment: You do it anywhere(model,view controller,helper,...). But it depends where you want.

Answer (score 1):

In Codeigniter you can get last query executed simply calling:

```
$this->db->last_query()
```

It return the last query executed as SQL String.

If you want to print it, use: `echo $this->db->last_query();`

source: [Codeigniter Official Docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html)